# In Jenkins pipeline how to pass a string that is read by a shell script from the stdin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, stdin

I have a jenkins pipeline. How can I "pass" a string as stdin to a shell script?

```
def getStatusJson() {
    if (this.statusJson == null)
        this.statusJson = slowHttpRequest()
    }
    return this.statusJson
}

def func1() {
    def json = getStatusJson()
    def command = ("echo '${pullRequestStatusJson}' | jq '.participants[] | select(.state=="changes_requested")' | jq '.state'")
    return sh (label: 'get PR change-requested state', script: command, returnStdout: true).trim()
}

def func2() {
    def json = getStatusJson()
    def command = ("echo '${pullRequestStatusJson}' | jq '.state'")
    return sh (label: 'get PR state', script: command, returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

The above code fails, most probably because pullRequestStatusJson has aposthropes, but anyway this doesn't seem to be a nice solution. How can instead of echo set the stdin of the shell script? Something like:

```
def json = getStatusJson()
def command = ("jq '.state'")
return sh (label: 'get PR state', script: command, returnStdout: true, stdin: json ).trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is as good as it gets with the standard `sh` step. You can write your own wrapper to accept `stdin`, but you already know that :)
When you pass somewhat complex strings (with a mix of single and double quotes) to `sh` it's easier to add a `withEnv` and let Jenkins do the escaping:

```
withEnv(["MY_STDIN=$pullRequestStatusJson"]) {
    sh '''echo "${MY_STDIN}" | jq '.state' '''
}
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow. I guess I'll still need to escape at least the double quotes with your example, don't I?

Comment: Nope, no escaping necessary because of how variable expansion in shell works

Comment: Just a note: If you care about security then withEnv should not be used for sensitive inputs (such as secrets or keys) without some consideration, since environment variables can be read by other processes.

Comment: @sfg That's true, for sensitive information Jenkins has `withCredentials`. But even that ends up as an environment variable, just the one that is masked in the logs.